# Entity Framework Adding Duplicate Values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to EF and I am trying to work with a many-to-many relationship.

I have a Developers table and I have a Applications table.

Each developer can have many applications, and each application can have many developers.

I have tried to follow examples on StackOverflow where it mentions to attach, but I've tried everything and it still creates duplicate developers for an application.

```
public class Developer 
    {
        public int DeveloperId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DeveloperName { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    }

public class Application 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public Developer Owner { get; set;}
        public virtual List<Developer> Developers { get; set; }
    }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Developer>()
                .HasMany<Application>(d => d.Applications)
                .WithMany(a => a.Developers)
                .Map(ad =>
                {
                    ad.MapLeftKey("DeveloperRefId");
                    ad.MapRightKey("ApplicationRefId");
                    ad.ToTable("DeveloperApplication");
                });
        }
```

Above describes my setup. I've tried so many things, but any time a new application is added, EF creates a new developer to associate with it.

```
                context.Applications.Add(app);
                   // no matter what I try here I get a duplicate developer
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(app.Id);
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: Where is the `Application.Developers` collection? And what's the purpose of `Application.Owner` property, which defines another one-to-many relationship between `Developer` and `Application`? Your issue might be related to that property rather than the may-to-many relationship.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the developers list on this post and have updated my question accordingly.  The purpose of Application.Owner is the 1 developer who is the lead on the project.  I suspect this may be indeed causing the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
public class Application 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public Developer Owner { get; set;}
}
```

To:

```
public class Application 
{
    private List<Developer> _Developers; 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="The Id Of Owner(owner as a developer) is Required")]
    public int DeveloperId { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("DeveloperId")]
    public virtual Developer Owner { get; set;}


    public virtual List<Developer> Developers { get{return _Developers;}} // This create Many to many

    public application(){
        _Developers= new List<Developer>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've made these changes, but I am still getting duplicate developers whenever I add a new Application.

Comment: when you create the Application, do not use  **owner = new Developer ()**, this creates a new developer and it is inserted into the database, better use DeveloperId = _(developer's id)_ *

Comment: example: `var app= new Application{DeveloperId=1, Name= "ExampleApp", Description= "an Example app" }; context.Applications.Add(app);
                   // no matter what I try here I get a duplicate developer
                context.SaveChanges();
                return Ok(app.Id);`  if on database not existe an develop with Id 1, the application dont save, but if existe this asigned to the developer with id 1

Comment: check my previous comment